Writing Code for Pulling PDF Date and putting into a csv table
Trying to create a code that pulls certain data using python and then creates a table in csv format to upload to excel. For some reason I am not able to pull dates or patient id but was able to get this far which is a huge step forward! LOL Can anyone help me achieve what I am trying to do? TIA
pip install pdfplumber
import pandas as pd
import pdfplumber
import re
from datetime import datetime  # Import the datetime module
# Defined PDF file path

pdf_path = "/content/drive/MyDrive/Final Project PDFs/Zoho Creator - Print              Queue Report.pdf"
# Open the PDF file

with pdfplumber.open(pdf_path) as pdf:
# Extract text from each page
text = ""
for page in pdf.pages:
    text += page.extract_text()

# Define a pattern to extract the Order Creation Date

order_creation_date_pattern = r"Order Creation Date (from New Cast Scan page).* (.+(\d+-[A-Z].*-\d+))"
# Find the Order Creation Date in the text

match = re.search(order_creation_date_pattern, text)
order_creation_date = match.group(1) if match else None
# Defined dictionary to map column names to their corresponding patterns

column_patterns = {
"Design File Name": r"Design File Name (.+)",
"Order Creation Date": r"Order Creation Date (from New Cast Scan page).* (.+(\d+-[A-Z].*-\d+))",
"Clinic Name": r"Clinic Name (.+)",
"Patient ID": r"Patient ID (.+)",
"Name on Shipping Label": r"Name on Shipping Label (.+)",
"Include Bungee Conversion Kit": r"Include Bungee Conversion Kit? (.+)",
}
# Add the "Closure" pattern

column_patterns["Closure"] = r"Closure Easily Removed (Splint) (.+)"
# Extract data based on the defined patterns

data = {}
for column, pattern in column_patterns.items():
data[column] = [match.group(1) if (match := re.search(pattern, text)) else None for text in text.split('\n')]
# Add the Order Creation Date to the data dictionary

data["Order Creation Date"] = [order_creation_date] * len(data[next(iter(data))])
# Creates a DataFrame from the extracted data

result_df = pd.DataFrame(data)
# Exports the DataFrame to a CSV file

result_df.to_csv("output.csv", index=False)
import pandas as pd
# Reads the CSV file

df = pd.read_csv("output.csv")
# Displays the DataFrame

print(df)
Output:
Design File Name  Order Creation Date         Clinic Name  
0                          NaN                  NaN                 NaN
1   AA2_HT_XX_RD_A_B_MON_410_8                  NaN                 NaN
2                          NaN                  NaN                 NaN
3                          NaN                  NaN                 NaN
4                          NaN                  NaN                 NaN
5                          NaN                  NaN  Monarch Wound Care
6                          NaN                  NaN                 NaN
7                          NaN                  NaN                 NaN
8                          NaN                  NaN                 NaN
9                          NaN                  NaN                 NaN
10                         NaN                  NaN                 NaN
11                         NaN                  NaN                 NaN
12                         NaN                  NaN                 NaN
13                         NaN                  NaN                 NaN
14                         NaN                  NaN                 NaN
15                         NaN                  NaN                 NaN
16                         NaN                  NaN                 NaN
17                         NaN                  NaN                 NaN
18                         NaN                  NaN                 NaN
19                         NaN                  NaN                 NaN
20                         NaN                  NaN                 NaN
21                         NaN                  NaN                 NaN
22                         NaN                  NaN                 NaN
23                         NaN                  NaN                 NaN
24                         NaN                  NaN                 NaN
25                         NaN                  NaN                 NaN
26                         NaN                  NaN                 NaN
27                         NaN                  NaN                 NaN
28                         NaN                  NaN                 NaN
29                         NaN                  NaN                 NaN
Patient ID Name on Shipping Label Include Bungee Conversion Kit  Closure  

0          NaN                    NaN                           NaN      NaN
1          NaN                    NaN                           NaN      NaN
2          NaN                    NaN                           NaN      NaN
3          NaN                    NaN                           NaN      NaN
4          NaN                    NaN                           NaN      NaN
5          NaN                    NaN                           NaN      NaN
6          NaN                    NaN                           NaN      NaN
7          NaN                    NaN                           NaN      NaN
8          NaN                    NaN                           NaN      NaN
9          NaN                    NaN                           NaN      NaN
10         NaN                    NaN                           NaN      NaN
11         NaN     Monarch Wound Care                           NaN      NaN
12         NaN      Dr. Jaqueline Gay                           NaN      NaN
13         NaN                    NaN                           NaN      NaN
14         NaN                    NaN                           NaN      NaN
15         NaN                    NaN                           NaN      NaN
16         NaN                    NaN                           NaN      NaN
17         NaN                    NaN                           NaN      NaN
18         NaN                    NaN                           NaN      NaN
19         NaN                    NaN                           NaN      NaN
20         NaN                    NaN                           NaN      NaN
21         NaN                    NaN                            No      NaN
22         NaN                    NaN                           NaN      NaN
23         NaN                    NaN                           NaN      NaN
24         NaN                    NaN                           NaN      NaN
25         NaN                    NaN                           NaN      NaN
26         NaN                    NaN                           NaN      NaN
27         NaN                    NaN                           NaN      NaN
28         NaN                    NaN                           NaN      NaN
29         NaN                    NaN                           NaN      NaN
I got this far which is a huge change but would like something like this...
Wanted Outcome
Pdf used looks like this...
Print Queue Report
Design File Name AA2Redo_HT_XX_RD_A_B_MON_410_8
Design Crea�on Date 08-Apr-2024
Order Crea�on Date (from New Cast Scan page) 08-Apr-2024
Shipping Comments
Clinic Name Monarch Wound Care
Custom Clinic Logo No
Custom Clinic Logo Text
Pa�ent ID AA2Redo
Scan ID 1
Full Name (admin)
Name on Shipping Label Monarch Wound Care
Contact Name on Shipping Label Dr. Jaqueline Gay
Address (Street Address) 200 Fort Pierpont Dr.
Address (Apartment, suite, unit, building, floor, Suite 105
etc)
Address (Department, c/o, etc)
Zip Code 26508
City Morgantown
State West Virginia
Shipping Method UPS 2nd Day Air
Referring Physician Jacqueline Gay
Include Bungee Conversion Kit? No
Include Sleeves? No
Design Comments
Pa�ent or Demo Pa�ent
Closure Easily Removed (Splint)
PCL (Strength) Coa�ng No
Print Priority Normal
Shipped? (admin) No
Print or Slice Only? Print in CO

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please format your code. Also check out PyMuPDF, fitz, pandoc
